# How to get min/max of second dimention of two dimentional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a two dimentional array like below. How to find the min and max values of the second dimention? (Without using loops)
var min = 1000 and max = 5000 in this case.

```
var myArray= [
  [1308888000000, 2962],
  [1308974400000, 2963],
  [1309060800000, 2965],
  [1309147200000, 1000],
  [1309233600000, 2970],
  [1309320000000, 2974],
  [1309406400000, 5000],
  [1309492800000, 2976]]
```

Comment: Without using loops?  What exactly do you mean? *Something* has to loop.

Comment: @Pointy I meant without using for or while statements

Comment: You could use hackery with regex and eval, but it's much cleaner to loop (with for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid (explicit) loops use an iterator function like `map` or `reduce`:

```
 max = Math.max.apply(null, myArray.map(function(x) { return x[1]}))
```

or

```
max = myArray.reduce(function(m, x) { 
    return Math.max(m, x[1])
}, myArray[0][1])
```

or sort the whole array by the second "column" and pick the first element:

```
max = myArray.sort(function(x, y) { return y[1] - x[1]})[0][1]
```